# Fragments show & hide

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 1 main fragment container and 4 fragments I wish to switch between via a bottom navigation bar.
I don't want each fragment to be reloaded every time it needs to be displayed (using the replace method).
I tried to use the following code to either load a fragment, if it wasn't previously loaded or show it if it was already loaded (and hide the previous one). For some reason, the hide and show don't seem to work.

```
       navigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

           int itemId = item.getItemId();

           Fragment fragment = getFragment(currentFragment);

           if (itemId == R.id.groupChatsIconItem) {
               if (fragment == null || fragment.getClass() != GroupChatFragment.class)
                   loadFragment(GROUP_CHAT_FRAGMENT);
           } else if (itemId == R.id.friendsIconItem) {
               if (fragment == null || fragment.getClass() != FriendsFragment.class)
                   loadFragment(FRIENDS_FRAGMENT);
           } else if (itemId == R.id.myProfileActivityIconItem) {
               if (fragment == null || fragment.getClass() != MyProfileFragment.class)
                   loadFragment(MY_PROFILE_FRAGMENT);
           } else if (itemId == R.id.directChatIconItem) {
               if (fragment == null || fragment.getClass() != DirectChatFragment.class)
                   loadFragment(DIRECT_CHAT_FRAGMENT);
           }
           return true;
       });

   }


public void loadFragment(String tag) {


       //if that's the first fragment - not adding to back stack to make sure the navigation view isn't being displayed alone.
       if (currentFragment == null) {
           currentFragment = tag;

           getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .beginTransaction()
                   .add(R.id.mainFragmentContainerView, getFragment(tag), tag)
                   .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                   .commit();
       }

       //The desired fragment isn't loaded yet.  loading it
       else if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) == null) {
           getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .beginTransaction()
                   .hide(getFragment(currentFragment))
                   .add(mainFragmentContainerView.getId(), getFragment(tag), tag)
                   .addToBackStack("yes")
                   .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                   .commit();
           currentFragment = tag;
       }
       //fragment was already loaded - hide the current one and show the new one
       else {
           Log.d("banana","desired fragment is already loaded");
           getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .beginTransaction()
                   .hide(getFragment(currentFragment))
                   .show(getFragment(tag))
                   .commit();
           currentFragment = tag;
       }
   }



private Fragment getFragment(String tag) {
       if (tag == null)
           return null;
       if (tag.equals(GROUP_CHAT_FRAGMENT))
           return new GroupChatFragment();
       if (tag.equals(FRIENDS_FRAGMENT))
           return new FriendsFragment();
       if (tag.equals(MY_PROFILE_FRAGMENT))
           return new MyProfileFragment();
       return new DirectChatFragment();
   }
```

I am not quite sure why the hide and show don't seem to work - as whenever I try to click to load a fragment for the first time its being loaded correctly, but once I tried to click a fragment that already have been loaded, it just doesn't change.
I have also tried separating the hide and load/show functions to two different ones - which didn't work. Any help will be highly appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue - instead of doing
`.hide(getFragment(currentFragment))`
I should’ve done
`.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(currentFragment))`
As i am looking to hide the fragment that is currently loaded in the container- and not a new one (getFragment returns a new Fragment for me).